# cc1plus.exe crash when using large precompiled header file

Tags: mingw, precompiled-headers, stack-size

I'm having an issue using precompiled header files with MinGW. The compiler seems to find the precompiled header file but cc1plus.exe crashes immediately after (cc1plus.exe has stopped working).

I've understood that this might be in connection with cc1plus.exe's low stack size, so I did the following to increase it:

```
editbin cc1plus.exe /STACK 33554432
```

and I also tried to no avail:

```
editbin cc1plus.exe /STACK 32768k
```

This however did not solve it as it still keeps crashing whenever I try to compile my application.

By the way I'm using the latest MinGw (gcc v 4.6.2) and the latest Eclipse CDT if that matters.

Am I increasing the stack size of cc1plus.exe correctly? 
Does anyone has any clue how to proceed, as I read through countless articles and topics but I'm kind of out of ideas for the moment.

g++ seems to find and accept my precompiled header file:

```
Building file: ../src/AdvancedOgreFramework.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNO_GCC_PRAGMA -I"C:\DevelopmentTools\workspaces\workspace_cpp
\MyGame\inc" -I"C:\docs\ogre3d\CEGUI\CEGUI-0.7.6\cegui\include\falagard" -I"C:\docs 
\ogre3d\CEGUI\CEGUI-0.7.6\cegui\include\RendererModules\Ogre" -I"C:\docs\ogre3d\CEGUI
\CEGUI-0.7.6\cegui\include" -I"C:\docs\ogre3d\ogre1.8.0_mingw_sdk\OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-0
\include" -O0 -g3 -H -Wall -c -Winvalid-pch -MMD -MP -MF"src/AdvancedOgreFramework.d" 
-MT"src/AdvancedOgreFramework.d" -o "src/AdvancedOgreFramework.o" "../src 
/AdvancedOgreFramework.cpp"
! C:\DevelopmentTools\workspaces\workspace_cpp\MyGame\inc/Precompiled.h.gch
```

And here is the makefile that I run as a pre-build make to generate my .gch:

```
C_FLAGS = -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -MMD -MP
INC_PATH = -IC:/docs/ogre3d/ogre1.8.0_mingw_sdk/OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-0/include -IC:/docs
/ogre3d/CEGUI/CEGUI-0.7.6-mingw/cegui/include -IC:/docs/ogre3d/CEGUI/CEGUI-0.7.6-
mingw/cegui/include/RendererModules/Ogre -IC:/docs/ogre3d/CEGUI/CEGUI-0.7.6-mingw/cegui
/include/falagard


all: Precompiled.h.gch

@echo 'Finished precompiling headers....'

Precompiled.h.gch: Precompiled.h    
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
g++.exe Precompiled.h $(INC_PATH) $(C_FLAGS)     

clean:
rm Precompiled.h.gch
```

The .gch is over 169 MB in size as I am trying to precompile most of the Ogre3D and CEGUI headers.

Thank you,
Adam.

Comment: Still not fixed in MinGW-w64 4.9.2  (opening PCH file of 180MB from wxWidgets-3.0.2 cases crash)

Comment: Still crash on a MinGW-w64 gcc 5.1.0(http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/dongsheng-daily/)

Comment: I just did a test on the cygwin g++ 4.9.2, and I don't see the crash issue. See my report here:https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56926#c12

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug report of GCC about your issue, see: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56926, it looks like big pch file(usually larger than 150M) can cause this issue.

Edit: 2015-05-31. I recently found a hard limit value for the pch file in GCC source for mingw or mingw-w64 toolchain, which is 128M. I would like to suggest some one to build a recent GCC to see whether it solve this crash issue. See my post in mingw-w64 forum: [[Mingw-w64-public] Set a larger pch file size limit? was : can anyone supply a debug version of cc1plus.exe?](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/34159267/)

Edit:2015-06-02. I can totally fix this issue by enlarge the hard limit value of the pch file, see my [Comment 17](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56926#c17) in gcc bugzilla.

Comment: @ollydbg12 and the report is over a year old and counting...  it sure looks like the gcc people are stumped on fixing this issue... Maybe they need to go onto SO and offer a bounty :P

Comment: Here is a good news: [MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows - Browse /Toolchains targetting Win32/Personal Builds/mingw-builds/5.2.0 at SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.2.0/) This release has the pch crash fix patch in, and works quite well.

Comment: @ollydbg12 now it just needs to make it into code::blocks' bundled mingw which the highest possible version is only gcc (tdm-2) 4.8.1 and that's in code::blocks' bleedingedge/custom/unstable distro

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe, the next TDM gcc release will have this patch applied, and C::B has bundled TDM gcc for a long time

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by updating mingw:

1. Run shell (cmd or sh)
2. Update package list:

   `mingw-get update`
3. After this run upgrade

   `mingw-get upgrade`

After this your mingw packages should be upgraded to latest versions and you should be able to get pased the error.